# JSF projects works on IE but throws an Exception in Google Chrome

Tags: jsf

My problem is my JSF Primefaces project is not running on Google Chrome when I try to run it.  It displays `the filename, item label, directory name, syntax is incorrect` and open  empty a notepad file.

The same project run on IE properly.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots or error messages for us to see what you're talking about? Also, post the exception stacktrace you are seeing in Google Chrome.

Comment: You need to provide more details for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the contentType with `<f:view contentType="text/html">` to your page.